# changes in binded object properties don't reflect in UI in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm new in Vue.js world. In my Vue app, there is a filtering system for products. It filters products by categories. I get the categories from backend with `axios` and save them in an array. But when I fetch these categories I also add new property for each category `selected` and give this property a default value `false`.

```
  <div class="options-block">
    <div class="option"><a :class="{'active': this.isAllSelected}" @click.prevent="selectCategory(null)" href="#">Все модели</a></div>
    <div
        v-for="category in this.categories"
        :key='category.id' class="option" :id='category.id'>
      <a  :class="{'active': category.selected }"
          @click.prevent="selectCategory(category)"
          href="#">{{ category.name }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { requestsMixin } from "@/mixins/requestsMixin";

export default {
  name: "Categories",
  data(){
    return({
      categories: [],
      isAllSelected: true
    })
  },
  methods: {
    selectCategory(category=null){
      if (category) {
        this.isAllSelected = false;
        this.categories.forEach(e => e.selected = category.id === e.id)
        this.$emit('categorySelected', category.id);
      } else {
        this.isAllSelected = true;
        this.categories.forEach(e => e.selected = false)
        this.$emit('categorySelected');
      }
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.getCategories().then(response => {
      this.categories = response.data;
      this.categories.forEach(category => {
        category.selected = false;
      });
    })
  },
  mixins: [requestsMixin]
}
</script>
```

In the `<template>` there is a case that I use the property to add a special class for categories. But switching from one category to another is not removing the class from switched category. How can I fix that? What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue is not able to detect changes on properties added to the object after it was assigned into `data` (your `selected` property) - see [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

Do this instead:

```js
beforeMount() {
    this.getCategories().then(response => {      
      response.data.forEach(category => {
        category.selected = false;
      });
      this.categories = response.data;
    })
  },
```